# Bloqueo inesperado PC - Driver gráfico

Tags: linux, gpu

Buen día a todos.

Recientemente me instalé una distribución de Linux en mi laptop, concretamente la de Parrot OS, y resulta que presenta bloqueos inesperados cada tanto tiempo (30 mins aprox), al momento del bloqueo la pantalla queda en negro y todos los componentes dejan de responder, por lo que es necesario reiniciarlo a la fuerza.

No hay un patrón concreto para reproducir el fallo, pero generalmente sucede momentos después de ver vídeos o streamings en el navegador.

Debido a ello, decidí revisar los logs del sistema y me encontré con lo siguiente:

```
    Jul 18 12:22:49 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2258.851578] [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2258.851805] [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.725951] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=492752, emitted seq=492754
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.726122] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process kwin_x11 pid 1283 thread kwin_x11:cs0 pid 1312
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.726129] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.959633] [drm] free PSP TMR buffer
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.992259] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: MODE2 reset
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.992299] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.992665] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2263.993115] [drm] PSP is resuming...
    Jul 18 12:22:54 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2264.013004] [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf40fc00000 for PSP TMR
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2264.243589] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2264.271745] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2264.530028] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091146] ------------[ cut here ]------------
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091264] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 92 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/core/dc.c:922 dc_commit_state+0x872/0xa30 [amdgpu]
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091278] Modules linked in: ctr(E) ccm(E) udp_diag(E) rfcomm(E) tcp_diag(E) inet_diag(E) nft_counter(E) nfnetlink_queue(E) xt_conntrack(E) nf_conntrack(E) nf_defrag_ipv6(E) nf_defrag_ipv4(E)
     xt_NFQUEUE(E) xt_tcpudp(E) nft_compat(E) nf_tables(E) nfnetlink(E) cmac(E) algif_hash(E) algif_skcipher(E) af_alg(E) bnep(E) nls_cp437(E) vfat(E) fat(E) snd_hda_codec_realtek(E) snd_hda_codec_generic(E) ledtrig_audio(E) snd_hda_codec_
    hdmi(E) snd_hda_intel(E) snd_intel_dspcfg(E) soundwire_intel(E) soundwire_generic_allocation(E) snd_soc_core(E) uvcvideo(E) snd_compress(E) edac_mce_amd(E) soundwire_cadence(E) snd_hda_codec(E) kvm_amd(E) kvm(E) irqbypass(E) btusb(E) s
    nd_hda_core(E) ath10k_pci(E) snd_hwdep(E) soundwire_bus(E) ath10k_core(E) snd_pcm(E) btrtl(E) btbcm(E) snd_timer(E) btintel(E) snd(E) ath(E) bluetooth(E) mac80211(E) soundcore(E) cfg80211(E) rapl(E) jitterentropy_rng(E) ideapad_laptop(
    E) videobuf2_vmalloc(E) videobuf2_memops(E) videobuf2_v4l2(E) videobuf2_common(E) drbg(E) wmi_bmof(E)
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091331]  videodev(E) hid_multitouch(E) sparse_keymap(E) ansi_cprng(E) serio_raw(E) libarc4(E) ecdh_generic(E) snd_rn_pci_acp3x(E) rfkill(E) ccp(E) mc(E) joydev(E) evdev(E) sp5100_tco(E) snd
    _pci_acp3x(E) efi_pstore(E) ac(E) tpm_crb(E) tpm_tis(E) tpm_tis_core(E) k10temp(E) ecc(E) pcspkr(E) watchdog(E) sg(E) tpm(E) rng_core(E) acpi_cpufreq(E) squashfs(E) loop(E) parport_pc(E) ppdev(E) lp(E) parport(E) fuse(E) configfs(E) ef
    ivarfs(E) ip_tables(E) x_tables(E) autofs4(E) raid10(E) raid456(E) async_raid6_recov(E) async_memcpy(E) async_pq(E) async_xor(E) async_tx(E) raid1(E) raid0(E) multipath(E) linear(E) md_mod(E) xfs(E) btrfs(E) blake2b_generic(E) xor(E) r
    aid6_pq(E) libcrc32c(E) ext4(E) crc16(E) mbcache(E) jbd2(E) crc32c_generic(E) nls_ascii(E) usbhid(E) sd_mod(E) t10_pi(E) crc_t10dif(E) crct10dif_generic(E) hid_generic(E) rtsx_pci_sdmmc(E) crct10dif_pclmul(E) crct10dif_common(E) crc32_
    pclmul(E) crc32c_intel(E) mmc_core(E) ghash_clmulni_intel(E) amdgpu(E) aesni_intel(E) ahci(E) libaes(E)
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091370]  gpu_sched(E) libahci(E) crypto_simd(E) i2c_algo_bit(E) ttm(E) cryptd(E) glue_helper(E) xhci_pci(E) libata(E) drm_kms_helper(E) xhci_hcd(E) cec(E) i2c_piix4(E) scsi_mod(E) usbcore(E
    ) usb_common(E) drm(E) rtsx_pci(E) wmi(E) battery(E) video(E) i2c_hid(E) hid(E) button(E)
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091386] CPU: 2 PID: 92 Comm: kworker/2:1 Tainted: G            E     5.10.0-6parrot1-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.28-6parrot1
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091387] Hardware name: LENOVO 81NB/LNVNB161216, BIOS AMCN22WW(V1.06) 05/10/2019
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091392] Workqueue: events drm_sched_job_timedout [gpu_sched]
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091495] RIP: 0010:dc_commit_state+0x872/0xa30 [amdgpu]
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091497] Code: e8 83 b7 00 00 48 8b 34 24 48 89 f7 e8 d7 a2 3c c1 e9 ea f9 ff ff 31 d2 e9 1b f9 ff ff 80 b8 78 03 00 00 00 0f 84 1d fe ff ff <0f> 0b e9 16 fe ff ff 4d 8b 87 78 03 00 00 41 8b
     b0 b0 02 00 00 85
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091499] RSP: 0018:ffffaee7803cbc58 EFLAGS: 00010202
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091500] RAX: ffff9e5160ac6400 RBX: ffff9e51ed4c0690 RCX: 0000000000000002
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091501] RDX: 0000000000000d5f RSI: 0000000000000820 RDI: 0000045e70b840af
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091502] RBP: ffff9e51ed4c0000 R08: ffffaee7803cbbac R09: ffffaee7803cbb20
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091503] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091504] R13: ffff9e51ed4c1ec8 R14: ffff9e51ed4c1ec8 R15: ffff9e5154410000
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091505] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9e5372e80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091506] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091507] CR2: 000035c809a24680 CR3: 0000000110012000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091508] Call Trace:
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091619]  dm_resume+0x3bc/0x520 [amdgpu]
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091722]  ? psm_adjust_power_state_dynamic+0xe8/0x1c0 [amdgpu]
    Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091799]  amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2+0x52/0xb0 [amdgpu]
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.091901]  amdgpu_do_asic_reset+0x25d/0x38d [amdgpu]
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092004]  amdgpu_device_gpu_recover.cold+0x66e/0x93f [amdgpu]
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092100]  amdgpu_job_timedout+0x11c/0x140 [amdgpu]
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092105]  drm_sched_job_timedout+0x72/0xf0 [gpu_sched]
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092115]  process_one_work+0x1b6/0x350
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092117]  worker_thread+0x53/0x3e0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092119]  ? process_one_work+0x350/0x350
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092121]  kthread+0x11b/0x140
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092123]  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x60/0x60
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092125]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.092128] ---[ end trace 7835ea5f8c37d662 ]---
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105247] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under SPG Mode).
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105257] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105259] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105260] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105262] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105264] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105265] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105266] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105267] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105269] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105270] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105271] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105272] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105273] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105274] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.105275] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.113860] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow start
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.113862] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow done
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.113864] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.113905] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(2) succeeded!
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.114016] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x114900320 flags=0x0070]
Jul 18 12:22:55 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2265.114022] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x114940000 flags=0x0070]
Jul 18 12:22:57 jromero-parrot dbus-daemon[649]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' requested by ':1.49' (uid=1000 pid=1445 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdev") (using servicehel
per)
Jul 18 12:22:57 jromero-parrot dbus-daemon[649]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.245234] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=492756, emitted seq=492759
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.245442] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process chrome pid 1828 thread chrome:cs0 pid 1858
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.245450] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.471348] [drm] free PSP TMR buffer
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.504362] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: MODE2 reset
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.504408] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.504776] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.505337] [drm] PSP is resuming...
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.525231] [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf40fc00000 for PSP TMR
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.747639] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2275.775388] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Jul 18 12:23:06 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.035919] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.208262] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under SPG Mode).
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.208275] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.208278] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.208281] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.208283] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.208286] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.216889] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow start
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.216893] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow done
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.216896] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.216982] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(4) succeeded!
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.217439] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.217489] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.217502] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.217509] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jul 18 12:23:07 jromero-parrot kernel: [ 2276.217573] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!

:
```

Lo cuál parece que fuese un problema con la controladora de video.

Sin embargo lo extraño es que es un problema que se me ha presentado justo también en Windows 10 y de la misma forma, el único SO dónde no he presentado este fallo es en Ubuntu 20.04, aunque de alguna forma siento el sistema menos fluido en este SO.

Mi PC es un AMD Ryzen 5 3500U con Amd Radeon Vega 8.

Agradezco si alguien que conozca del tema me pudiera brindar su ayuda.

Muchas gracias.